# Determine whether the following limit exists and either find the limit or prove it doesn’t exist.

Tags: real-analysis

The limit is that I have to prove the existence of is $\lim_{(m,n)\rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{m^3-n^3}{m^2+n^2}$. My first thought was to factor ${m^3-n^3}$ into $(m-n)(m^2+mn+n^2)$ and try to evaluate it from there. Past that I am struggling on were to take this proof. I am just for looking for help in starting this proof, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: for this one, polar coordinates work

Answer (score 3):

Note that the limit along $m=0$ and the limit along $n=0$ are trvially seen to be $0$.

For $m \neq 0$ and $n \neq 0$ we have $0\leq |\frac {m^{3}-n^{3}} {m^{2}+n^{2}}|\leq \frac {|m|^{3}+|n|^{3}} {m^{2}+n^{2}}\leq  \frac {|m|^{3}} {m^{2}}+\frac {|n|^{3}} {n^{2}}\leq |m| +|n| \to 0$.  Apply Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: How did you break up the denominator like that in the third step of the inequality?

Comment: @JohnBeaver $m^{2}+n^{2} \geq m^{2}$ and $m^{2}+n^{2} \geq n^{2}$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It looks like you used squeeze theorem to show this right? Doesn't this have to be shown without the absolute values to hold of all m,n?

Comment: @JohnBeaver By definition of limit $a_{nm} \to 0$ and $|a_{mn}| \to 0$ are one and the same statements. Write down definition in terms of $\epsilon$ to see this.

Comment: +1...............Another way: Let $u=\max (|m|,|n|).$ Then $u>0$ and $|m^3-n^3|\le |m|^3+|n|^3\le 2u^3$ while $m^2+n^2\ge u^2.$

Comment: +1 : elegance...

Comment: $(m,n)\to 0$ usually allows $m=0$ or $n=0$ (but not both). But you have $m^2$ and $n^2$ as denominators simultaneously.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I have added an extra line to my answer.